# using geocoder of opentripplanner

Tags: java, tomcat, transit

I am developing a webapp using opentripplanner. I have followed 2 and five minute tutorials at their websites, there is also a opentripplaner-geocoder.war webapp, but i am unable to figure out that how can i use this geocoder.

Answer (score 2):

To work with geocoder in OTP please refer to this post. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentripplanner-dev/OQ8Ld1ZxQCA)

There are some slight improvements to the above post though( I have to spent hours to figure them out!), these are as follows

**For Google basemap**

1. In `config.js` just add these codes after the OSM declaration in baselayers:

   ```
    new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
              "Google"),
   ```
2. Add the Google Maps API script tag to `index.html` in the directory `otp-opnlayers-client/src/main/webapp/` (or `otp-leaflet-client/src/main/webapp/` depending on version):

   ```
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
   ```

**For Google Geocoder**

1. In `config.js` set `enabled : true` or (depending on version) add the following block to the `otp.config` variable:

   ```
   geocoders : [
        {
               name: "Geocoder",
               className: "otp.core.Geocoder",
               url: "/otp-geocoder/geocode",
               addressParam: "address",
        }
   ]
   ```
2. In
   `application-context.xml`, under
   `otp-geocoder/scr/main/resources/org/opentripplanner/geocoder/`, 
   change the value of `ref` of the `geocoderServer` bean to `geocoderGoogle`:

   ```
   <bean id="geocoderServer" class="org.opentripplanner.geocoder.ws.GeocoderServer">
           <property name="geocoder" ref="geocoderGoogle" />
   </bean>
   ```
3. Build and restart the server. Then try `http://localhost:8080/otp-geocoder/geocode/?address=18.516446,73.851751`.

P.S. - I'm working on a latest version of opentripplanner i.e. `SNAPSHOT 0.9`